# how to deploy theme BigCommerce

Tags: sass, bigcommerce

I have downloaded the theme, how can I post it on my website after fixing the error?
I have searched for instructions on the internet but have not solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are only able to upload a theme that has been zipped up using the Stencil CLI `stencil bundle` command. For more information on how to install and use Stencil CLI onto your machine, review the following documentation:

- https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/installing-stencil
- https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/stencil-cli-options-and-commands

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stencil cli to do this. Try using command `stencil push` which bundles the theme files and uploads the theme to BC. There will be activation steps that should follow this command. More info can be found here:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/stencil-cli-options-and-commands